# Shopping cart output

Tags: php, mysql

I have an online store. A products page that allows the user to view a product and add it to the basket. It is added to the basket by clicking "Add to basket" button.

When a user clicks "add to basket", the script redirects them to the basket page and adds the product to the basket.

My question is, how do I print the basket output on the "basket.php" page? How do I pass the session content into variables to be printed?

Thank you.

"products" table in the database:

```
id int(11), name varchar(255), price int(11)
```

product.php

```
 ...

<form id="basket" name="basket" method="post" action="basket.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to basket"/>
</form>

...
```

basket.php

```
<?php 
 //add product to cart with product ID passed from previous script 
    if (isset($_POST["p_id"]))
     { 
        $p_id = $_POST["p_id"];
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$p_id'"); 
        $is = mysql_fetch_row($q); $is = $is[0]; 

        $result = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        $name = $row["name"];
        $price = $row["price"];
        $info = $row["info"];
    }

    $result .= $name .= $price .= $info;


        //$_SESSION['p_id'] contains product IDs 
        //$_SESSION['counts'] contains item quantities 
        // ($_SESSION['counts'][$i] corresponds to $_SESSION['p_id'][$i])
        //$_SESSION['p_id'][$i] == 0 means $i-element is 'empty' (does not refer to any     product)


        if (!isset($_SESSION["p_id"])) 
        { 
            $_SESSION["p_id"] = array(); 
            $_SESSION["counts"] = array(); 
        } 
        //check for current product in visitor's shopping cart content 
        $i=0; 
        while ($i<count($_SESSION["p_id"]) && $_SESSION["p_id"][$i] != $_POST["p_id"])     $i++; 
        if ($i < count($_SESSION["p_id"])) //increase current product's item quantity 
        { 
            $_SESSION["counts"][$i]++;
        } 
        else //no such product in the cart - add it 
        { 
            $_SESSION["p_id"][] = $_POST["p_id"]; 
            $_SESSION["counts"][] = 1; 
        } 
    } 

?>



<div>

<?php echo $result ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Is this a custom shopping cart or 'out-of-the-box'? Have you tried, print_r($_SESSION) to see whats actually being stored into the session?

Comment: I just need a simple shopping cart to show products, the simplest it can be I do not mind. This is what is being printed when I run "print_r($_SESSION); Array ( [p_id] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => ) [counts] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) [cart] => [p_id] => Array ( [0] => 76 [1] => 11 ) )

Comment: $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$p_id'");  Loop through that query. It should contain the product details for the product they're adding. Without knowing the database structure its hard for me to tell where the products would be.

Comment: Is that what you mean? It didnt work (check the edit)

Comment: Does name, price and info columns exist in the database? Also, make sure you're getting rows back from that query. You could check with mysql_num_rows. You could also run that query manually in the database to see if anything gets returned.  EDIT: make sure you're getting inside of the first IF statement too.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create ajax request on button click, to basket.php with GET veriable todo='add_to_basket', witch you will handle in basket.php

HTML of you add product button or link

```
<a href="#" onclick="add_to_basket(<?=$YOUR_PRODUCT_ID?>)"></a>
```

Your count of product, you will get by Jquery, just type your count html selectors with IDs

```
<select id="count_<?=$YOUR_PRODUCT_ID?>"></select>



function add_to_basket(product_id){
var product = {};
product['prod_id'] = product_id;
//here you get count of current product
product['count'] = $("count_"+product_id).val();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "your_domain/basket.php?todo=add_to_basket",
  data: "product",
  success:function () {
  }
});
}
```

on your basket.php you handle this request like that

```
if ($GET['todo'] == "add_to_basket"){
  // here you add your data(witch comes from ajax) to SESSION
  $_SESSION['basket'] [$GET['prod_id']] = $GET['count'];
  return true;
}
```

then when user click on basket image you redirect him to basket page, in wich you display all product in session

```
<?foreach ($_SESSION['basket'] as $item){?>
// here you get product info by product id from your database and product count from $_SESSION  print it to view , price wille be count*price

<?}?>
```